# Uninterruptible power supply - How it manages to provide electricity to electronic devices before it shutting down?

Tags: computers, ups, latency

I believe there is a lag in time (I think the latency for the switch over can take some milliseconds) when a switch over to the battery backup happens. I understand the electric appliances like motor, bulbs may not have much impact if the latency is less. However when it comes to electronic devices, example a computer processor which has its clocks works for every nanosecond, how will those maintain the working in the UPS latency?

Comment: Think about it. The power is AC anyway. It goes to zero or near zero for many miliseconds each cycle anyway. It is just not that big of a deal as long as the switchover is fast. Capacitors can hold up DC voltages for much more than a few ms.

Comment: You seem to be confusing SPS with UPS - SPS has a switching time, UPS does not.

Comment: the UPS does not power the processor ... the PC power supply powers the processor

Answer (score 2):

Its usually the inverse, most devices on the mains are built with enough input capacitance to handle at minimum a full mains cycle missing, so when the UPS detects the mains cycle not lining up with what it expects, it switches on its inverter stage

In the UPS it would normally keep its bulk DC rail charged up, this does consume some small amount of power, but it means the reaction time can be very short,

So the UPS has detected an issue, it disconnects the input mains from the output, and with a very short delay starts switching its inverter using that charged up bulk rail.

due to all this, the device is very unlikely to ever see more than 1 mains cycle without external power.

Answer (score 1):

A large caopacitor, charged to the peak of the power line voltage, is the method.

Assume 1,000 uf rated at 450 volts, charged to 120 * 1.414 == 170 volts.

The stored energy is 0.5 * C * (V * V) or

- 0.5 * 0.001 farad * (170 * 170) == 0.6 * 0.001 * 28,900 == 14.5 joules (watt_seconds)

If your discharge this capacitor by 50% in 1/120  second, you can provide 7 * 120 or over 800 watts without dropout. You just have to recharge it, fully, every half cycle of the power line.

If you only need 200 watts, you can skip to every 2 full power cycles.

If you only need 80 watts, you can tolerate 5 cycles of dropout.

=============================

Suppose you have a full-wave rectifier, which for 60Hz power will recharge the cap 120 times a second. The recharging, for light loads, occurs only at and right after the peak, maybe for a few 100 microseconds.

The other 8,000+ microseconds of energy come from the capacitor.

For progressively heavier loads, the recharge begins earlier and earlier, not waiting for the peak.

Comment: Thanks. I have less knowledge in electrical engineering. Do you mean the capacitor power the electronic device when there is a slight lag?. Do the capacitor comes in to action only if there is a power drop or the capacitor power the device always(the main line is the input to the capacitor and further things handled by capacitor always?)